# GeoServer not infilling Polygons in WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I am trying to make a WMS service for complicated Polygons using geoserver pointed at postGIS.

When some of the polygons are being rendered by the WMS the polygon fill crosses the geometry of the polygon, see the image for a better idea of whats going on.

Why is the polygon not being styled correctly?

My geoserver version is 2.7.6, the polygon has a srid of 3857
[image: WMS fill not respecting geometry of Polygon]

SLD for the Polygons in question :

```
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>feature</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>Depths</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>300000</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>1000000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>          
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a5bfdd</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Issues like that have been fixed in the past, 2.7.6 is really old, try a 2.12.x release instead. I don't remember particular workarounds, sorry.

Comment: are you sure the polygon is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the Geoserver version from 2.7.6 to 2.12.2 fixed the issue.